# send variable from pug to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend, pug

this code displays a list of doctors from the database, and after the user choose a doctor I redirect him to "/user/new_diagnosis/doctor/"page , what I want is to send the doctor id that the user chooses to the server so I can be able to use it in "/user/new_diagnosis/doctor/"page , pleas any idea how can i do it

server.js

```
app.get("/user/new_diagnosis",checkNotAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
    db.query(
      `SELECT * FROM doctor`,
        (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
           res.render("user-diagnosis",{doctors: results, name: req.user.userName ,surname: req.user.userSurname });
        }
      );

  });
  
  app.get("/user/new_diagnosis/doctor",checkNotAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
    res.render("user-diagnosis-doctor");
  

  });
```

.pug

```
extends user-layout 

block content 
    div.container-fluid
        div(class=["row", "pt-4"])
            div(class=["col-md-3", "col-sm-5", "d-md-flex", "flex-column", "border-end"])
                h3(class=["text-black", "py-4", "text-center"]) Select A Doctor
                form.d-flex.mb-3(role="form", action="/", method="get")
                    input.form-control.me-2(id="doctor-search", name="doctor-search", type='search' placeholder='Search' aria-label='Search')
                    button.btn.btn-outline-success(type='submit') Search 

                each doctor  in doctors
                    .list-group
                        a.list-group-item.list-group-item-action.d-flex.gap-3.py-3(href= `/user/new_diagnosis/doctor/`, aria-current='true')
                            svg(xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", width="50", height="50", fill="currentColor", class=["bi", "bi-person-circle", "pe-1"], viewBox="0 0 16 16")
                                path(d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z")
                                path(fill-rule="evenodd", d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z")
                            .d-flex.gap-2.w-100.justify-content-between
                                div
                                    h6.mb-0= "Doctor "+ doctor.doctorName +" "+ doctor.doctorSurname
                                    p.mb-0.opacity-75= doctor.hospitalName
                                small.opacity-50.text-nowrap now
            div(class=["col-md-9", "col-sm-7", "px-4"])
                //-form(role="form", action="examination_card", method="post")
```

[image]

Comment: The classic way if doing it is to GET `/doctors/:doctorID`.You could have a route in Node/Express like `app.get("/doctors/:doctorID", (req, res) => ...` and then you get the ID in `req.params.doctorID`. You can then look for the document in you database, you get the full Doctor object, you use it to render your Pug template, and finally you send the rendered template (that is, HTML) to the browser as a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't passing the `doctor.id` to the front-end, there isn't a way to access it.

To fix this, you can add the doctor's ID to the anchor href in your `.pug`

```
href=`/user/new_diagnosis/doctor/`+doctor.id
```

Then in `server.js`, update your endpoint to take an id

```
app.get("/user/new_diagnosis/doctor/:doctorId", ...
```

Finally, access the variable with

```
req.params.doctorId
```

Disclaimer: this solution is untested, but should lead you down the right path.